# Is this an undefined behavior in C?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

I am running my C code on gcc to understand pre/post increment operator.
However the results that I see are not what I expected. Like for the line 6, since i is 5, it should have been

```
8 7 6 5 5
```

But it is `8 7 6 5 8`

Then coming to the last line, it displays `14 14 14 14`. Can someone please explain this behavior. I had expected 
`14 14 13 12`

Is this compiler dependent? Is the beahviour of printf function on sequence points undefined?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        i = 5;
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d \n", i, i++, i++, i++, i);
        printf("%d \n", ++i);
        printf("%d \n", ++i);
        printf("%d \n", ++i);
        printf("%d %d %d %d \n", i, ++i, ++i, ++i);

}
```

Comment: It is undefined behaviour. Your expectations are not supported by the C standard

Comment: It can't be explained, it's undefined behavior. You can't put multiple increments of the same variable into a single statement.

Comment: Moral of the story: Avoid Pre/post increment in 99% of situations. Readers of your code will appreciate it.

Comment: @Alexander I appreciate your comment. Intent is to understand how increment operators work, for self evaluation.

Comment: @aschepler: The suggested duplicate is about C++. I'm sure there's a duplicate that's about C, but I haven't found it.

Comment: @Shankhadeep. Moral of the story is use the operators within their range of applicability and you'll be fine.

Comment: @MadPhysicist makes things lot clear now.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji you will want to carefully read [C11 Standard 6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

And these are the places where you will find sequence points:

- at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full expression
  is an expression statement, or any other expression which is not a
  subexpression within any larger expression);
- at the `||`, `&&`, `?:` and comma operators; and
- at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and
  just before the actual call).

An elaboration of the last point: the comma operators in a function call are *not* sequence points and the expressions between the `,`s can be evaluated in any arbitrary order.

Check [this](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) and [this](http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html) for better understanding.

In `printf("%d %d %d %d %d \n", i, i++, i++, i++, i);`, you are writing to the same memory location more than once between two sequence points, thus invoking [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for pointing that out. Edited.